# Print received data from client in NodeJS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

I have a simple html file containing that piece of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.X.X:8080',
            data: '{"data": "1"}',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data) {
                    var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
                    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'Error: ' + error.message;
                }
            });
    </script>
```

I simply want my NodeJS server to print data received (there: the number 1°).

Here is my NodeJS code:

```
var http = require('http');
var s = http.createServer();
s.on('request', function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    console.log('a: '+request.method);
    console.log('b: '+request.headers);
    console.log('c: '+request.url);
});
s.listen(8080);
```

Server is receiving requests just find but how to retrieve the value of the data sent?
I just want server to receive a number from client and print it. How to do that?

Many thanks1

Comment: req.body should give you the data

Comment: console.log('d: '+request.body); returns "d: undefined" :(

Comment: Try change             data: '{"data": "1"}', to             data: {"data": "1"},

Comment: Still the same. If that helps here are the results I obtain: a: GET
b: [object Object]
c: /?callback=jQuery11130008525234181433916_1443819273435&data=1&_=1443819273436
d: undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what your looking for.

```
#!/usr/bin/node 

var http = require('http');
var s = http.createServer();
s.on('request', function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200);
    console.log('a: '+request.method);
    console.log('b: '+request.headers);
    console.log('c: '+request.url);

    var url = decodeURIComponent(request.url);
    var startPos = url.indexOf('{');
    var endPos = url.indexOf('}');
    var jsonString = url.substring(startPos, endPos+1);
    json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    console.log(json['data'])
});
s.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see jsonp works using the http module, you could use something like that (I wouldn't advise using this in any of your code, it's just for the demonstration):

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  var query = querystring.parse(req.url.split('?')[1]);
  console.log(query);
  res.end(query.callback + '({"Name": "Foo", "Id": 1234, "Rank": 7})');  
}).listen(8080);
```

Note: when using jquery jsonp data should better be an object, not a string (see https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)

You should, however, ask yourself:

1. Why jsonp?
2. Is there a module that does all that for you & parse JSON, help you with errors/authentication/etc? I usually use https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi (It supports jsonp if you really need it), there other modules like express.